# Python pickle wrong encoding

Tags: python, sockets, pickle

I'm sending some data over a socket connection. I have a clock ticking in a thread. From there I yield the result to another function;

**Midi.py**

```
def startClock(self):
        frame_rate = 24
        interval = 1. / frame_rate
        while True:
            if self.playing:
                for i in range(0,8):
                    #do some irrelevant stuff here
                    quarter_frame = '0x{}{}'.format(i,x)
                    quarter_frame = int(quarter_frame, 16)
                    clock = [0xF1, quarter_frame]
                    yield(clock)
```

**Main.py**

```
def startClock(self):
    clock = midi.startClock()
    for i in clock:
        client.sendMessage(i)
        print(i)
```

which outputs the following on the Client-side and which is correct:

```
[241, 12]
[241, 16]
[241, 38]
[241, 48]
[241, 64]
[241, 80]
[241, 96]
[241, 112]
...
```

When I send it over to the server, like this:

```
def sendMessage(self, message):
    self.s.send(pickle.dumps(message))
```

I get an iteration, like the following (which differs from time to time, but seems to go from 1 - 16):

```
[241, 0]
[241, 2]
[241, 3]
[241, 4]
[241, 5]
[241, 7]
[241, 8]
[241, 9]
...
```

Here I receive the messages:

```
def receiveMessage(self, conn, addr):
    try:
        while True:
            data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(1024))
            print(data)
```

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: hm. you could use base64 encoding http://base64encode.net/python-base64-b64encode to see if it's really an encoding problem

Comment: why do you have two `startClock(self)` methods?

Comment: the one in Main.py handles the button click and the other one starts the clock.

Comment: if you want to post the full code in pastebin, I will try and see if I can reproduce your error.

Comment: base64 encoding doesn't seem to fix it at first sight. I'll have a better look at it tomorrow

Comment: That would be very kind of you. I just pasted all code underneath each other http://pastebin.com/5ZJk1DMH, I have 5 seperate files (Main.py, Midi.py, Audio.py, Client.py and Server.py) pasted in the same order.

Comment: What is the `x` variable used in the `'0x{}{}'.format(i,x)` call in `midi.startClock()`?

Comment: First I get the low nibble from the frames (SMPTE time), then the high nibble from the frames. Then low and high nibble from the seconds, minutes and hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted an answer here yesterday, but it seems to be removed. Anyway, if I change the size of the bytes to send, I receive the correct output on the other side of the wire.
So

```
data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(1024))
```

should be

```
data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(12))
```